# When clicking on OneDrive tile, it displays About Me page instead of user's OneDrive for Business documents page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, onedrive-for-business, mysites

After restoring a database backup WITH REPLACE to the MySites content database, to bring over from prod all site collections to the test farm (both MinRole SharePoint 2016 farms), in the test farm, when a user clicks on OneDrive tile, it is displaying About Me page instead of user's OneDrive for Business documents page.

When the user goes to Site Contents, the "Documents" library is not showing up. But in my case I am able to see the "Documents" library under Site Contents in my OneDrive (I am a farm admin).

What could be causing this and how to fix it so the other users can access the Documents library in the test farm when they click on the OneDrive tile which should take them to https://mysites/personal/username/Documents/Forms/All.aspx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The step I was missing was to run a full crawl on all content sources. After this, the link got fixed and OneDrive for Business (default document library in a user's MySites) was showing up after clicking on OneDrive tile.

Answer (score 0):

Setting up OneDrive for Business in a SharePoint Server on-premises environment requires Managed metadata service application, User Profile service application and My Sites are running on your farm.

Please make sure you have configured these services correctly after migrating My Sites content database.

[Set up OneDrive for Business in a SharePoint Server on-premises environment](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/sites/set-up-onedrive-for-business)

Besides, make sure the my site web application is allowed to Create Personal Site. Go to Manage web application->click relevant web application->Self-Service site creating management, select “On” to allow users create their own site collection.

Comment: All services mentioned are running properly. My issue here is that I have all site collections in CA related to all the users' URL for /personal/username and I am missing the connection of that with OneDrive for all the users except for my account which is pulling everything correctly when I click on the OneDrive tile. In this case I don't need to create a new site as all of them are already existing and being reported as site collections under the Web Application.  What am I missing here?